# In Apache Camel with Spring Boot, how to Join many external callbacks (using "from().to()") into a single response?

Tags: java, apache-camel, aggregation, spring-camel, camel-spring-dsl

**SOLVED! Scroll down to Solution.**

I have entity Person with some basic data on table A and more specific data on tables B, C, D, etc (address, for example).

PersonResponseDTO (summarized):

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test"
}
```

AddressResponseDTO (summarized):

```json
{
    "person_id": 1,
    "street": "Test St."
}
```

These data come from an external API called using `from("direct:getPersonById").to(getPersonUrl)` and `from("direct:getAddressByPersonId").to(getAddressUrl)` (summarized).

I created a third object called AggregatedPersonResponseDTO:

```json
{
    "person": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test"
    },
    "address": {
        "person_id": 1,
        "street": "Test St."
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to **join both responses in a single request**, returning an object of type AggregatedPersonResponseDTO, only using the Camel API? I want to use both response objects to build the third one. And I will have use cases in the future with more than two "joins".

### Solution explanation

1. It's not needed to set streamCaching to either true or false.
2. Not needed to set HTTP_PATH.
3. Code in the Camel route:

```java
from("direct:getFullPersonByIdService")
    .toD("http:{{endpoints.get-person-by-id}}?bridgeEndpoint=true")
    .pollEnrich(
        simple("http:{{endpoints.get-address-by-person-id}}?bridgeEndpoint=true"),
        5000,
        new PersonAggregationStrategy(),
        false
    )
    .unmarshal(new JacksonDataFormat(GetAggregatedPersonResponseDTO.class))
```

The content between double curly-braces is read from the application.yml or application.properties.

4. The whole PersonAggregationStrategy class:

```java
@Log4j2
public class PersonAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(final Exchange exchangePerson,
                              final Exchange exchangeAddress) {
        log.info("Aggregating Person and Address...");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final GetAggregatedPersonResponseDTO aggregatedPerson = new GetAggregatedPersonResponseDTO();
        aggregatedPerson.setPerson(objectMapper.readValue(exchangePerson.getIn().getBody(String.class), GetPersonResponseDTO.class));
        aggregatedPerson.setAddress(objectMapper.readValue(exchangeAddress.getIn().getBody(String.class), GetAddressResponseDTO.class));

        exchangePerson.getIn().setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(aggregatedPerson));
        log.info("Aggregated object => {}", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(aggregatedPerson));

        return exchangePerson;
    }

}
```

5. I also had to implement the TypeConverters interface for the resulting object of the aggregation:

```java
@Component
public class AggregatedPersonConverter implements TypeConverters {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public AggregatedPersonConverter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Converter
    public InputStream getAggregatedPersonResponseDTOToInputStream(GetAggregatedPersonResponseDTO source) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

            oos.writeObject(source);

            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    }

}
```

6. I don't know if it works for more than two callbacks. Maybe it will need other implementations of AggregationStrategy. I'll test this use case some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to model a route which **enriches** the first web service result with  the second one. The way you merge both responses has to be specified in your `AggregationStrategy` instance.

See the enrich EIP:
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/enrich-eip.html

Comment: Thank you! After fiddling with the code a bit, it works! I'll edit my question with the whole solution and some more details about things I had to do.